# virtuemart hook for custom thankyou page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Hey i need to develop a custom plugin for custom thankyou page in VirtueMart
How should i achieve that , because thank you page is generated according to the payment selected.
What is the correct hook for changing the last thank you page in VirtueMart.
I tried plgVmConfirmedOrder but is that the correct hook? how to achieve this thing using virtuemart hook system?

Comment: You can develop thankyou page WITHOUT editing payment plugin depends on what you need to echo on thankyou page

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a plugin for custom `thankyou` page. You just go and modify or override the template file `order_done.php` at the location given below-

> *components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/order_done.php*